# Do you know who I'm talking about?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix contains a dangerous drug, it messes with your mind.
>
> But next to things like heroin, this one's rather kind.
>
> In fact, it is accepted, its hazards oft ignored
>
> It's there to pick you up if you should become bored.
>
> My infix is good at what it does, some might say a pro.
>
> I'd bet Without using it once, a day you couldn't go.
>
> It's one of the more social words, scarcely used alone.
>
> Both the speaker and the spoken have company of their own.
>
> Next up is the ultimate weapon, in more than one way.
>
> Unlike a sword, its power grows with each and every day.
>
> Put down the weights, you can't wield this with sheer brute force and
>   might.
>
> For it is the very definition of power, revealed within the light.
>
> Once you have it, chop it in half, you need some help to wield it
>
> It takes millions to cultivate, alone you are unfit
>
> Your half is important, and equally as grand.
>
> For now you are holding my suffix in your hand
>
> You now have all three parts, and the hero is revealed
>
> Yes, it is a name, behind this riddle sealed.
>
> This one might be tricky, but do give it a try.
>
> And if you think you've figured it out, then tell me: Who am I?

Hint:

> It's been quite some time since I gave you this rhyme
>
> No progress been made, and I'm not surprised
>
> This one was a difficult riddle to write
>
> And to solve, but be sure, the end is in sight.
>
> First up for the prefix, a clue to help you out
>
> The drug that it contains is sprinkled all throughout
>
> The marketplace today, in pills, drinks and bars
>
> but my prefix delivers the most of it by far.
>
> My infix is a letter, but also a word
>
> the usage of which should not be ignored.
>
> Commonly used in casual conversation
>
> To try not to speak it would lead to frustration
>
> My suffix, half the weapon of ultimate might,
>
> To be up against it would be quite a fright.
>
> You may have your guns but still you will cower
>
> When it's used right, my suffix is power.
>
> You have more to go on, a path to go down.
>
> I'd advise you to take a quick look around.
>
>  Things are often connected, with quite a common theme.
>
>  It might help you out, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Another awesome riddle! *”The speaker and the spoken”* sounds really nice. $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: @cubemaster Hint? :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie for you? anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *know*!!!

You're

> [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593/joe-you-know)

Prefix

> Joe like coffee

Infix

> You for "u"

Suffix

> Know for knowledge

Comment: Is this better @cubemaster ?

Comment: Damn, I thought that would actually be a bit harder. Good job!

Comment: I guess that's the problem with setting a precedent. Makes it easy to get the meta riddles

Comment: @joe-you-know look at this!

Comment: Lol I don't even know if he's seen the riddle

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Expansion

The first part is

> Ex or X, short for the drug Ecstasy

Middle is

> pan, everyday object and social word, as in frying pan, sauce pan, pan and teller. oops.

Last part is

> fission, half of that, rounding up, is -sion

=====================

Second Guess

Are you

> T. S. Eliot?

First part

> T  because Tea contains caffeine, a drug which fits the description

Second part

> Cell (S. El), a social word (cell phone, blood cell, dry cell, etc)

Third part

> don't look here, i have nothing.  I feel like an id-iot, so I'll use that IOT to finish

Comment: *”Pan and teller”* Hahah, love that reference! I would upvote if I did not reach my daily voting limit (DVL)...

Comment: Not what I had in mind,  but not a bad start! However, I don't quite know if I would consider ecstasy to be an "acceptable" drug.

Comment: added second guess

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably too tired to think straight, but I'll give it a shot.

Answer

> Potter

Prefix

> Pot. Commonly, marihuana is referred to as pot. It's not so harsh on the user, or so people say.

Infix

> T. Tea is not used alone most of the time. We add milk, lemon, etc. to it. We also invite people to drink it. And then, Tea sounds like T.

Suffix

> Er. Power is literally power. We split it in half and get Pow and Er. Er is the smaller half, but it is "equally important" since it is the one we need.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Enoki (mushroom)

prefix:

> 'E'
>  I think this is referring to the medical abbreviation of epinephrine (E), which is another name for adrenaline. Adrenaline can be described as a 'drug' that is not stigmatized, and activities which create adrenaline are good when you are bored.

infix:

> 'no'
> because 'no' is a social word that is commonly used in phrases ex.'no thank you'. It is hard to get through a single day without saying the word 'no'.

suffix

> 'ki'
>  I think 'ki' or 'qi' literally translates to 'air', which we are all 'holding in our hands' right now. 'qi' is also half of the phrase 'qi gong', which is involved with martial arts. A person's 'ki' is supposed to  grows with each and every day (as the riddle suggests) if it is cultivated. It is not a skill that can be wielded using physical strength but requires mental training and cultivation.

Finally,

> 'Enoki' is a name (albeit of a mushroom)

Comment: Not a bad start, but look at that first line there. My prefix **contains** a drug. Not the other way around