# When Will I Be Served?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> My prefix's mind is quite fair and precise.
>
> My suffix can flow with a warm sacrifice.
>
> My infix is shown in a shuffle and worn.
>
> My lady, though blind, balances with a thorn.

**What am I?**

The answer is $7$ letters, and the title is a clue. Oh, and don't fear that `knowledge` tag; it only exists because of the lady, so perhaps you might have to research, but only after you know the answer.

---

**Fun Fact:**

Just noticed that an anagram of `loving riddles` is `riddle solving`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Justice

My prefix's mind is quite fair and precise.

> Just

My suffix can flow with a warm sacrifice.

> Ice

My infix is shown in a shuffle and worn.

> If you anagram "usti" you get suit (clever :D)

My lady, though blind, balances with a thorn.

> [Lady justice statue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Justice)

Title

> Justices is served!

Comment: Yes! But that's not the particular word I'm after. I'm sure you will find it, though :D

Comment: Oh, damn. But you are so very close. You are $100\%$ on the right track! And it's also been a while since you have last answered one of my riddles. **Edit:** The prefix is correct; the suffix is correct; the lady is correct; the explanation for the title is correct :D

Comment: All you have left is the infix to explain :P

Comment: Is this better @user477343, and I guess it has been a while since I've answer a puzzle of yours :D +1 from me

Comment: Yup! You got it! I have to wait $2$ hours before I can upvote your answer, though :)

Comment: I spent my last upvote on @Cubemaster 's [most recent riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71077/do-you-know-who-im-talking-about) only because I think there might be a badge earned when you get $10+$ votes on a question (so hopefully he gets that). That means you won't be getting an upvote (for now....) but you will be getting a $\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$. Congratulations! :D